# Twilio webhook (2-way) functionality -- How to disable SSL certificate validation for webhook testing

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

For testing Twilio webhook, I selected the "*Disable*" option under "**SSL certificate validation**" but I've kept running into a problem in that the "*Save*" button doesn't seem to act on it -- or even do anything! (Please see [the attached screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cokBPXM1C1aFZaLoEnVxY-Q0pyLGsY0-/view?usp=sharing)).

And when I re-logged back to my account, the "*Enabled*" option is still there/selected!

Thanks in advance if you could point out how one can disable the SSL certificate validation for Twilio webhook testing purposes.

Regards,

-Nam Nguyen

Comment: This question should be asked of [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact). It's not a programming question, so it can't be solved on Stack Overflow.

I wouldn't recommend disabling SSL certificate validation in general.